# Use single view with two different layouts in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This might be a weird question, but I have two layout files in my project and I have a single view I'd like to render separately in each layout file (depending on URL).

So the issue I have is when I define the sections in the view. Both layout pages have similarly functioning sections, but they are named different. For example, if I wanted to use layout1 it would be `@section main1` and for layout2 it would be `@section main2`.

The view will render the same content within these sections, so can I dynamically set the section name rather than making two copies of the same content with just the section name changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily change the layout page by setting the layout you want to use, but you can't dynamically set the name to my knowledge.  If you really can't change the section names of one of them, what you could do is create a nested layout of the one, and in that nested layout define section names that match in the nested one.

Basically you define:

```
@section a
{
   @RenderSection("namethatmatchesotherlayout")
}
```

And through this you can get something that matches.

Comment: I pretty much stumbled on to this solution myself.  it's definitely the cleanest way to do it.